# Good online auction software

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script

We are looking for some PHP-based auction software to start off with and I have have been scouring the net many times and am almost ready to purchase [phpprobid](http://www.phpprobid.com) as this seems to be the best and most feature rich of the lot; only bad things I have read is the lack of after-sales customer service.

Others I have also looked at include:

- [AJ Auction Software](http://ajsquare.com/products/auction/index.php)
- [WeBid](http://www.webidsupport.com/)
- [GuruScript Auction](http://www.guruscript.com/auction.php)
- [PHP Auction (enuuk)](http://www.phpauction.net/).

Many of them turn me off by having unprofessional sites which makes me think their software will be the same and be rubbish. Many also don't go into detail with the feature set like PHP Pro Bid does.

So before we purchase PHP Pro Bid I was wondering if I missed something good?

Thanks!

Comment: Any specific features you're after?